# Can't access an object as an element value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating a registration form. So, at some point, the user has to choose where he lives, from a list of cities, that I get from a web service.

Now, there is the chance of two (or more) cities having the same name, so the web service also gives me a unique ID corresponding to each city.

I create a select element and populate its options with the cities I get from the web service, setting the unique ID as the option's value, so far so good (don't mind the pipe, it just orders the options alphabetically).

**.html file:**

```html
<select
 class="form-control"
 formControlName="province"
 id="province"
 (change)="loadCities($event.target.value)">
   <option *ngFor="let item of provinces | sortBy:'asc':'name'" [value]="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Now the problem I have is, that at the end of the registration process, I need to show the user a summary. I have the city's unique ID stored in my form, *but I don't want to show him the ID*, I want to show him the **name** (he can't do anything with the ID, he wouldn't even know to which city the ID belongs).

So I've tried to set the object (which looks like `{id: 10, name: 'Rapid Rivers' }`) instead of just the ID as the option's value:

**.html file:**

```html
<select
 class="form-control"
 formControlName="province"
 id="province"
 (change)="loadCities($event.target.value)">
   <option *ngFor="let item of provinces | sortBy:'asc':'name'" [ngValue]="item">{{ item.name }} 
   </option>
</select>
```

but then, when I try to access the object from my `loadCities()` function, like this:

**.ts file:**

```
loadCities(selectedValue) {
   console.log('city id: ' + selectedValue.id);
   console.log('city name: ' + selectedValue.name);
}
```

I get **this**:

[image: object properties are undefined!]

Why wouldn't you just ask the web service for the city's name providing its ID you may think, as I've tried that solution too...
The web service doesn't allow me to ask for a city name by providing its ID, and I can't modify it because I don't have access to it. So I wonder how could I set maybe two values (name and ID) to the option value, when the dropdown is created? And how can I access those values later, to show either the ID or the Name of the city, but not both at the same time?

Or can you think of a better solution for my problem? I know I might be overthinking it at this point, but my brain just stopped working

I'm using reactive forms.

Comment: are you using reactive forms?

Comment: The way you are binding the select doesn't seem to be the way, say, [Angular's tutorial shows how to bind a select](https://angular.io/guide/forms#build-the-form).

Comment: yes, i edited my question to show that, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, it seems you are using the reactive form.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: 'province',
  });

  this.onChanges();
}

onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.get('province').valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue => {
    console.log('city id: ' + selectedValue.id);
    console.log('city name: ' + selectedValue.name);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like that! but why doesn't it work with `(change)="loadCities($event.target.value)"` ?

Comment: It's because your value isn't an object it's the value of your select option. If you just console log "selectedValue" it will be the option's value.

Comment: But i am not doing that. In the function, i'm actually doing `console.log(selectedValue.id)` and getting 'undefined' as a result...
 My question is why when retrieving the option's value through `$event.target.value` i can't access the object, but when retrieving it via `this.myForm.get('province').valueChanges...` i can?